# ng-repeat slider outside of the range [1, 100] gets it stuck at 0 or 100

Tags: angularjs

As seen in this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/dn1hxXE115TKoiefNtD2?p=preview), when using `ng-repeat` to create `input type=range` elements with values either less than 1 or greater than 100, the slider position appears initialized at either `0` or `100` instead of the appropriately bound value (which in the example means the slider button should all be right in the middle).

Is this a bug with `ng-repeat` and how can this be fixed?

Comment: chrome 31 seems to work. which browser do you use?

Comment: Using chrome 32 beta, I can try some other browsers though

Comment: chrome 31 and ff min values all 0 in safari 0.25,0,0; max values in all browsers: 0.5, 500, 50. can't test IE ;)

Comment: Tried in Chrome Canary and Safari 7.0.1 with the same broken result. Slider did not show up at all in FireFox.

Comment: The issue is the slider positions are wrong, they should all be in the middle. @Michael Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: no, only the last one is in the middle. the first at 0%, the second at 25%

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45070/discussion-between-michael-and-user1027169)

Comment: This is an open Angular issue: [Add support for the input type=range](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1189)